# SQL Transaction in Distributed .Net Web API and Multiple Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, transactions

Since I am using .Net core WebAPI and I have two APIs (API1, which is configured to use DB1 in the connection string), then API2, which is configured to use DB2 in the connection string, and then I have the Ocelot API gateway.

So whenever I have to make changes in both databases using two APIs, I want my code to be able to roll back in both databases if some exception occurs.

I am using MySql also not EntityFramework.

I was learning about the choreography architecture. And whenever I tried searching for solution I came across `ApiTransactionScope`, which is a bit confusing for me, I don't know how to implement in a way to roll back both db.

Comment: This is not really going to be about databases as the two database transactions will not be aware of each other's existence. A rollback may not even be a rollback on database transaction level as the successful API call may complete before the error from the other API surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the Saga design pattern.

It is suited for cases such as yours, when you have distributed web services.
It can take a while to get your head around it, and it is not necessarily simple to implement, but it can be a powerful tool.

There are even some libraries that can help you, although I have not used them so I can't really recommened any.

There are plenty of resources online which can explain this much better than I can, in detail, so take a look at some such as:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/saga/saga

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html